# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have been through many other questions that have similar errors but don't see what is wrong with my code. Can you identify how to fix `ts(7053)` error.

The full error I am receiving is

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ card: number; dialog: number; navigation: number; layer: number; blanket: number; modal: number; flag: number; spotlight: number; tooltip: number; }'.
```

The code is

```
const zIndexToName: Record<number, string> = Object.keys(layerIndex).reduce(
  (acc: Record<number, string>, name: string) => {
    const value: number = layerIndex[name]();
    acc[value] = name;
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);
```

Whereas, `layerIndex` is

```
export const layerIndex = {
  card: 100,
  dialog: 300,
  navigation: 200,
  layer: 400,
  blanket: 500,
  modal: 510,
  flag: 600,
  spotlight: 700,
  tooltip: 800
};
```

I can switch out all `string` to `any` but get the same error, of `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type`

```
const zIndexToName: Record<number, any> = Object.keys(layerIndex).reduce(
  (acc: Record<number, any>, name: any) => {
    const value: number = layerIndex[name]();
    acc[value] = name;
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the index type for `layerIndex`.

```
export const layerIndex: { [key: string]: number }
```

and I suppose the function call on the number is a mistake. It should be

```
 const value: number = layerIndex[name];
```